# Union of continuous images of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

The continuous image of a compact set, $L \subseteq X$, is compact. But how about if I have a set of continuous operators $F \subseteq A$ where $A = \{ \text{continuous operators } T:L \rightarrow X\}$, $A$ endowed with a sensible topology, and I am interested in the *union* of the images of $L$ under all $T\in F$. That is, I want to look at the topological properties of $\cup _{T\in F} T(L)$.

I have stated this in full generality above, in case there is something that can be said. However I am actually particularly interested in the case of linear combinations of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, I have a compact set $L \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a closed set $ T\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. What are the topogical proterties of $\{\Sigma_{i=0}^{n}t_i x_i | (t_i)\in T \text{ and } x_i \in L \ \forall i=0,...,n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set could be anything. If $Y$ is any space and $S$ any subset, then you can take $L=\{x\}$ to be some singleton subset of $X$ and $F$ to be the union of $|S|$-many maps sending $x$ to each point of $S$.

The same thing can be done in the case of your second question. Consider $L=\{1\}$, $T=\Bbb{R}\times\{0\}$. The $\{\sum_{i=0}^1 t_ix_i|(t_1,t_2)\in T,x_i\in L \forall i=1,2\}$ is all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah so perhaps the key is the boundedness of T. I thought that the conditions above would be enough to say something meaningful. Though what I am workin with in my problem is $T = \{(t_i)| t_i \geq 0 \ i=0,...,n \ , \ , \Sigma t_i = 1\}$

Comment: @Meep Ah, in that case, I think the the set would be compact. I think it would be the convex hull of $L$.

Comment: yes, but why is it compact :/? That was actually the main purpose of my question. I just hoped something more interesting could be said in generality. I suppose I should have asked directly

Comment: @Meep Perhaps you should post another question, I'm sure someone will answer it. You need to show the convex hull of a closed, bounded set is closed and bounded - I think it shouldn't be too hard